# Which one is optimal to use DbFactory or IDbConnection in order to create a generic database helper class

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

Hi 
I developing a common helper component for database access, so that one can use it any database server he wants, that is basically supported by ADO.Net. Earlier I was using IDbConnection for that purpose. But I came across DbFactory class that has built in provider specific functionalities, so no need to re-invent the wheel.

But in MSDN forum i found a discussion that DbFactory has some performance issues , when it was used under loops. So that guy finally switched to IDbConnection.

So , I just want to know, which one will be good to implement and in what aspects like speed, re-usability, Exception handling and extendibility etc.

Please , inform if missing anything or is not clear... thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean DbProviderFactory?

Comment: I'd agree with k3b then, I'd use the factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Donot think that performance differences will matter much in normal usage-scenarios.

Do you have a link to the discussion about performance problem?

If you do not need to be compatible with dotnet 1.1 I would recommend the System.Data.Common classes (including DbFactory) because these classes are easier to use and more powerful than the bare interfaces.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f97b3bbe-2089-4d7c-9a76-c429a1e0dd8f/